# Error generating orderer block Genesis in customized hyperledger fabric 2.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I changed all the configuration files to set up a network that currently contains 5 organizations of a peer each. As long as there are 3 organizations everything works perfectly, when I insert the other 2 I get the following error, could someone suggest me a solution?
Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEnlX.png)

Comment: error clearly stated that something is wrong with `configtx.yaml` file. i guess some formatting issue.

Comment: Resolved.
The problem was a badly set tab in the configtx.yaml file, thanks for the help.